# invoke adapter from PHP script

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am sending push notification to all devices and for that i have created adapter for tag based push notification as follows.

```
function sendTagNotification(applicationId, notificationText, notificationTags) {
    var notificationOptions = {};
    notificationOptions.message = {};
    notificationOptions.target = {};

    var tags = notificationTags.split(",");

    notificationOptions.message.alert = notificationText;
    notificationOptions.target.tagNames = tags;

    WL.Server.sendMessage(applicationId, notificationOptions);

    return {
        result : "Notification sent to users subscribed to the tag(s): '" + notificationTags + "'."
    };
}
```

now the approach we want is , we will be having the php script which will send the message content to Worklight Adapter and `sendTagNotification` adapter will receive the message content and send it to all mobile users.

so is there any way to invoke adapter from PHP script ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MobileFirst 7.0 and above, and your adapter procedure is protected with a security test, you would need to implement what is termed a "confidential client" in order to act as an OAuth client that handles the OAuth challenege: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_non_mobile_to_mobile_services.html

Another way this can be done is to have the PHP script call the adapter procedure URL, but that adapter procedure must be unprotected using securityTest="wl_unprotected". For example using curl, with the parameters in the URL body: `curl http://my-host:my-port/project-context-root/adapters/adapter-name/procedure-name`

If using MobileFirst 6.3, you can invoke the adapter procedure from the Studio (right-click on the adapter folder and select Run As > Invoke MobileFirst adapter procedure) and enter some details. A browser window will open.

You should be able to copy the URL that will be there and adjust the appended parameters in your script...

Comment: our client is using `v 6.3` so i think i have to choose the second option , i understood the url part to access the adapter but how can i pass the parameters

Comment: i am getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException:File not found: /adapters/WLPush/sendTagNotification`

my end point is `http://192.168.100.32:10080/RR_MobileApp/adapters/WLPush/sendTagNotification`

Comment: Actually if you are using 6.3 that URL structure won't work. It assumes REST which is also part of 7.0 and above... hmm. I'll get back to you...